# ¿Como puedo filtrar los registros de una tabla que no esten en otra con linq C#?

Tags: c#, linq

Por ejemplo tengo una tabla "tabla1" con los campos id y nombre. Tengo otra tabla "tabla2" con los campos id, idtabla1 y descripción. Lo que busco es realizar una consulta con linq que me devuelva los registros de la tabla1 que no aparezcan en la tabla2.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Si no sabes cómo hacer lo que describes en tu pregunta, investiga primero y actualiza tu pregunta con los enlaces de la investigación que hayas hecho. Hasta que no añadas mas información, me temo que tu pregunta quedará [en espera-¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 1):

Lo que buscas es un left join en linq

[Cómo: Realizar operaciones de combinación externa izquierda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/bb397895.aspx)

podria ser algo como

```
var query = from t1 in tabla1
            join t2 in tabla2 on t1.id  equals ts.idtabla1  into g
            from subt2 in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { 
                t1.nombre, 
                t2 = (subt2 == null ? String.Empty : subt2.descripción) 
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que lo que buscas es lo que en SQL se logra con una condición `NOT IN`, que en LINQ sería algo así:

```
var query =
    from t1 in tabla1
    where !(
        from t2 in tabla2
        select t2.idtabla1
    ).Contains(t1.id)
    select t1;
```

Comment: Hice algo parecido pero la segunda consulta la pase como un arreglo con el id